# Many to Many and HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I got class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurants")
public class Restaurant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    (...)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_restaurant_owner",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="username")})
    private List<User> owner;
```

How to get Restaurant if I know User ("owner") username?

> Query q = session.createQuery("from Restaurant as r where r.owner = :username").setString("username", username);

it doesn;t work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to join to a collection in HQL if you are selecting on properties of the element within the collection.

```
from Restaurant r join r.owner o where o.username = :username
```

Comment: I think this will return the owner's details as well. From my experience you don't need to do a join, you can just chain the property `r.owner.username = ...` in this case only the Restaurant details should be returned.

Comment: This is an explicit join, vs. the implicit join.  In my experience (which was over a year ago) I had trouble without the explicit join when attempting to query based on a property of an associated entity.  In any case, it should return Restaurant entities and the owner list of the Restaurant should be populated since it isn't marked as lazy.  You could change it to select r from Restaurant r join r.owner o where o.username = :username.  Here's the docs for join http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: Good point about the `Fetch.EAGER` and you're right about the explicit versus implicit join. For *this case* however simply chaining the properties would provide a simpler query.

Comment: I agree you have a point on the properties.  All I know is that in my experience (again, haven't touched HQL for over a year) I had problems if I didn't do an explicit join.  Perhaps they have fixed it since then.

Comment: Seems as if the asker has lost interest or can't be bothered with voting any answer up. +1 to your answer from me :-)

Comment: I'll reciprocate since we gave essentially the same answer.  Also, poster can't up vote since he doesn't have 15 rep yet.

Answer (score 1):

`from Restaurant as r` should be `from Restaurant r` no `as` (not sure if as is optional).
Also, you do `r.owner = ...` this should be `r.owner.username = :username`

Answer (score 0):

`r.owner` references the PRIMARY KEY of the Owners table.

what you want is a subselect (done in SQL here for simplicity - I'm not too confident with HQL):

```
select {r.*} from Restaurant as r where r.owner = ( select id from Owners as own where own = :username ).setString("username", username)
```

this way, you match the foreign key with the field it references, rather than the name field.